# Initialize view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

All the code that I will present for example.
I have ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public User SomeUser { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {

    }
    public ViewModel(int id)
    {
        SomeUser = someservice.getUserById(id);
    }
}
```

I have controller

```
    public partial class SomeController
    {
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var model = new ViewModel(id);
            return View("Documents/Edit", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(ViewModelmodel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TempData["Save"] = true;
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = model.Id });
            }
            return View("someview", model);
        }
}
```

In view I have form  and on view I display

```
<b>Model.SomeUser.Name</b>
```

When I go to SomeController/Edit/3.In viemodel someUser property initialize in constructor.But when I do postback my viewmodel initialized constructor without parameters and if modelstate is not valid, someUser property is null.So I get null reference exception.
What is the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 4):

Your `ViewModel` shouldn't really be responsible for calling services, it should just be a simple representation of what to display in your `View`. I'd keep it simple.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public User SomeUser { get; set; }
}
```

So your regular Edit action can initialize the *SomeUser* property from your service.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = new ViewModel()
    {
        SomeUser = someservice.getUserById(id);
    };
    return View("Documents/Edit", model);
}
```

Now for the post. The `id` should still be in the query string when you submit your form, so you can bind to it in the parameters of your action as well as the model which holds the form data.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        TempData["Save"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
    }
    return View("someview", model);
}
```

Now, I'm now sure what your `View` looks like, but as is, your `ViewModel` doesn't contain any properties which can be submitted and bound. This is an edit user page you might be after a `ViewModel` which represents the things you're editing.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var user = someService.getUserById(id)
    var model = new ViewModel()
    {
        Username = user.Username,
        Age = user.Age
    };
    return View("Documents/Edit", model);
}
```

Now if you use the Html helpers in your form...

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Age)
```

... then your properties will be automatically bound in the post action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = someService.getUserById(id);

        user.Username = model.Username;
        user.Age = model.Age;

        TempData["Save"] = true;
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
    }
    return View("someview", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends entirely on your requirements.

For the code in your question, you can just reuse your GET method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ViewModelmodel model)
{
  if ( !ModelState.IsValid ) return Edit( id );
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be described with more details. What pattern do you use?

1) If MVC (because of SomeController class and ActionResult) then:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, ViewModel model) {
if (ModelState.IsValid) {
TempData["Save"] = true;
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = id });
}
return View("someview", model);
}
```

this should work.

2) If MVVM (because of ViewModel) then you may use MVVMlight which can help you by messages:

//send from your ModelView:

```
Messenger.Default.Send(“Hello world”);
```

//in another ModelView add this:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, DoSomething);
```

// Further

```
private void DoSomething(string message) {
// what to do with it...
}
```

but here I had problems with Galasoft...Win8.dll